# How to make google.android.gms.common.SignInButton accessible via TalkBack

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I've been working on making our app more accessible for user's using it with TalkBack. One issue I've ran into is the Google [SignInButton](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton) announces itself as "Button" via TalkBack (not even "unlabeled").

I've tried setting its contentDescription both in xml and code like other views in the app, but it hasn't made a difference to this behavior.

Any ideas on how to get this view to announce itself as "Google Button" for instance would be much appreciated!

If it helps, this is what the view looks like in the xml:

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/google_sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During debugging I found that SignInButton has a single child element. Setting the contentDescription on this child element got the correct behavior from TalkBack. Here is the code:

```
SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) view.findViewById(R.id.google_sign_in_button);
signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_ICON_ONLY);
signInButton.setScopes(mGso.getScopeArray());
signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        googleSignIn();
    }
});
if (signInButton.getChildCount() > 0) {
    View signInButtonInnerContent = signInButton.getChildAt(0);
    signInButtonInnerContent.setContentDescription(getString(R.string.google_button_description));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a content description?

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/google_sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/some_localized_string"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: Yes I did, and it still had the same behavior.

Comment: Did you try setting it programmatically after the view is rendered?

Comment: I found the answer! Will post below.